# Static members and unnamed namespaces

Tags: c++

I try to properly understand how static and unnamed namespaces relate to each other and the behavior of data members and functions in various scopes. However I haven't been able to find one place that lists all these cases.
I wrote down my own explanation for my team's "C++ technical reference" but first I'd like to have confirmation that what I wrote down is correct.

So here we go:

What effect does static have on data members and functions?

- On a class data member: The same as in C# and Java, the member is shared across all instances of the class.
- On a named namespace or global member: The member is only visible by the current translation unit. Every translation unit that uses it will have it's own copy.
- On a class function: The function cannot access non-static data members and class functions, it has no this pointer.

A named namespace or global member that is static is equivalent to one that is inside an unnamed namespace.
Both make it visible only to the current translation unit. The use of unnamed namespaces is preferred over static.

In general a global or named namespace member that's not static or inside an unnamed namespace is wrong.
Linking multiple object files with this kind of members that have the same name or signature will either result in a linker error or all but the first occurrence of the member be omitted.
This last possibility is not something you usually want.

**Is what I described here correct?**

Comment: I can't really see a question in there. What  did you want to ask?

Comment: You answer your own question? See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static) for what `static` means in different contexts

Comment: You forgot the case of `static` local variables, and you should probably cover lifetime as well as visibility and linkage.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox The question is if what I describe here is correct.

Comment: @StanWijckmans I added the question for you, but I still think it is too broad. I am pretty sure that for each single point you can find questions and answers here, but covering all uses of static is a bit too much